# Prononciation de "2h41"

Tags: prononciation, indications-de-temps

J'ai entendu dans la télévision l'expression "2h41" prononcée "deux heures quarante-et-une". Pourquoi dit-on "quarante-et-une" et non pas "quarante-et-un" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parce qu'il s'agit en fait de minutes :

> deux heures quarante-et-une [minutes]

Comment: Oui, c'est la forme correcte mais « deux heures quarante et un »  s'entend de plus en plus.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux s'entendent mais le féminin, où « une » s'accorde avec « minutes » qui est sous-entendu mais jamais prononcé, est la forme habituelle et considérée comme correcte.

Je n'ai jamais entendu personne dire « minuit moins **un** », en revanche, dans un compte à rebours, il n'y a jamais d'accord avec *seconde*, pourtant aussi féminin :

> cinq, quatre, trois, deux, **un**, zéro.

Voici quelques (rares) exemples trouvés où l'accord n'est pas fait:

> L'affichage luminescent indiquait une heure quarante-et-**un**. *Il est un autre temps* Dominique Durand.
>
> [Il est neuf heure quarante-et-**un**](http://arnaudmaisetti.net/spip/spip.php?article1509)
>
> [Dix-huit heures quarante-et-**un**](http://www.1951.fr/pochettes-1951/549-python-rouge.html)

L'absence d'accord peut se justifier, comme dans l'exemple du compte à rebours, quand les minutes sont lues comme un nombre sans unité. Le nombre *quarante-et-une* n'existe pas, *un* ne s'accordant que lorsqu'il est utilisé comme déterminant.